# Django Rest Framework: Trying to use serialisers with a OnetoOne relationship - not pulling related data through

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework, nested, one-to-one

So I am creating a project where we have Projects, and each Project has multiple Pledges (one-to-many relationship - each pledge assigned to one project, each project has multiple pledges).

Pledges can optionally have a Condition assigned to them, which is a OnetoOne relationship. A condition on a pledge is optional, but each Condition has exactly one Pledge. Each pledge has either 0 or 1 conditions.

I have written serializers/views to return pledges and projects. I want the condition of each pledge to display alongside the pledge, so for a specific pledge it will also retrieve the condition description from the condition table.

However, I can't get further than showing the pledges. I cannot make it also show the related condition for a pledge. What am I doing wrong??

My models are;

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.URLField()
    goal = models.IntegerField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()
    goaldate = models.DateTimeField()
    is_open = models.BooleanField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='owned_projects')

class Pledge(models.Model):
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pledge_date = models.DateTimeField()
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project',on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='pledges')
    supporter = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='pledges'
    )

class Condition(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    conditionmet = models.BooleanField()
    pledge = models.OneToOneField(Pledge, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,related_name='pledge')
```

and my Serializers:

```
class ConditionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Condition
        fields = '__all__'

class PledgeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    supporter = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='supporter.id')
    conditions = ConditionSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Pledge
        fields = '__all__'

class PledgeDetailSerializer(PledgeSerializer):
    conditions = ConditionSerializer(read_only=True)
    # How do I bring in the relevant project's detail, here????????????????

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.amount = validated_data.get('amount',instance.amount)
        instance.comment = validated_data.get('comment',instance.comment)
        instance.pledge_date = validated_data.get('pledge_date',instance.pledge_date)
        instance.project = validated_data.get('project',instance.project)
        instance.supporter = validated_data.get('supporter',instance.supporter)
        instance.condition = validated_data.get('condition',instance.condition)
        instance.save()
        return instance 


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.id')

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'

class ProjectDetailSerializer(ProjectSerializer):
    pledges = PledgeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.goal = validated_data.get('goal',instance.goal)
        instance.image = validated_data.get('image', instance.image)
        instance.is_open = validated_data.get('is_open', instance.is_open)
        instance.goaldate = validated_data.get('goaldate', instance.goaldate)
        instance.date_created = validated_data.get('date_created',instance.date_created)
        instance.owner = validated_data.get('owner', instance.owner)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

views;

```
class ProjectList(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def get(self, request): 
        projects = Project.objects.all()
        serializer = ProjectSerializer(projects, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ProjectSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(owner=request.user)
            return Response(
                serializer.data,
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            )
        return Response(
            serializer.errors,
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        )
        # else:
        #     print(serializer.errors)

class ProjectDetail(APIView):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
        IsOwnerOrReadOnly
    ]

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            project = Project.objects.get(pk=pk)
            self.check_object_permissions(self.request, project)
            return project
        except Project.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
    
    def get(self, request, pk):
        project = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = ProjectDetailSerializer(project)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def put(self, request, pk):
        project = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = ProjectDetailSerializer(
            instance=project,
            data=request.data,
            partial=True
        )
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(
                serializer.data,
                status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT
            )
        return Response(
            serializer.errors,
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        )

class PledgeList(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def get(self, request):
        pledges = Pledge.objects.all()
        serializer = PledgeSerializer(pledges, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = PledgeSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(supporter=request.user)
            return Response(
                serializer.data,
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            )
        return Response(
            serializer.errors,
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        )

class PledgeDetail(APIView):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
        IsSupporterOrReadOnly
    ]

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            pledge = Pledge.objects.get(pk=pk)
            self.check_object_permissions(self.request, pledge)
            return pledge
        except Pledge.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk):
        pledge = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = PledgeDetailSerializer(pledge)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def put(self, request, pk):
        pledge = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = PledgeDetailSerializer(
            instance=pledge,
            data=request.data,
            partial=True
        )
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(
                serializer.data,
                status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT
            )
        return Response(
            serializer.errors,
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

I have tried switching to a ForeignKey to at least getting it working that way. I have tried putting the OnetoOne on the condition instead of the pledge.